# On submit throws ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My controller is not being called from view page on submit instead it's getting an error message as  soon as I hit the submit button.

**Error: An item with the same key has already been added.**

StackTrace:

```
[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +9382923
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) +252
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) +91
   System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext.get_PropertyMetadata() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) +392
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +147
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +2504
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +548
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +473
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +181
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +830
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +136
```

Comment: a guess - you have two elements in the form with the same id.

Answer (score 3):

Your view model might have had two properties with the same name, such as UserName and userName. When MVC does model binding, since it is not case sensitive, it will think you have two identical properties.

Comment: after 7 years ;it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Might need some more code to answer your question, like the Aciton Method and the Form.

My guess is the model binding is trying to add two form values with the same name/ID and failing there, so I'd check your view code to make sure you aren't using the same ID tag twice.